# 1 column full width while aligning content of 2nd column to overall page container

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to build the following properly.

I have a flex row with one column spanning the full 50% with an image spanning the full background, while the second column is meant to have content which still aligns to the overall container of the page (max-width 1200px).

The issue I'm having is, that while the right column aligns with its content to the page's container, it now is very small in width overall.

Is there a way to align it to the container but have it be wider in width?

Here is the codepen for it:
https://codepen.io/lisaschumann/pen/qBmRMWX

```
<section class="container">
  <h1>Website</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut enim. Pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae. Eget dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius quam quisque. Sed blandit libero volutpat sed. Morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa. Quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut enim. Pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae. Eget dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius quam quisque. Sed blandit libero volutpat sed. Morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa. Quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
</section>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column left"></div>
  <div class="column righ text-align">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut enim. Pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae. Eget dolor morbi non arcu risus quis varius quam quisque. Sed blandit libero volutpat sed. Morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa. Quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
}

.left {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1613585574494-200c873926e1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.text-align {
  max-width: calc(1200px - 50%);
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you failing to produce? Width `calc(1200px - 50%)` is not 50% of container but 600px is. I would save container width to some variable and calc it `width: calc(var(--container) / 2)` and used `max-width: 50%;` for mobile (as long as container is 100vw). Something [like this](https://codepen.io/Jaxp/pen/yLbgRoK).

Answer (score 1):

The approach shown in https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/ can be modified here to achieve what you want.

Ditch the `text-align` class completely, and add `container` on the `row` element, to have *that* limited to the max width.

The left column then gets a negative margin-left, and a padding-right to offset that again, as follows:

```
margin-left:   calc(-100vw / 2 + 600px / 2);
padding-right: calc( 100vw / 2 - 600px / 2);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s8nm0wj1/

Comment: Thanks @CBroe! https://codepen.io/lisaschumann/pen/JjNEeXY I've input it into a new codepen. If I add padding to the right column though, it moves the left colum further away. Do I have to deduct anything on the margin/padding for the left one in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Just checked your code. I think your soution will be at `text-align` class. Inside that you are using `max-width: calc(1200px - 50%);`. Actually this is not needed. Since you have added `container` class for your section, it has a `max-width: 1200px`. So you can set

```
.text-align {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

This will automatically adds white space after the content.

**Working Example** https://codepen.io/devkr/pen/xxdgyao

Answer (score -1):

If you want to widen the text maybe try selecting the class right and its p tag and making the text wider, like this:

```css
.right p{
  width: 550px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Juan. I think with this it wouldn't align with the page's container anymore. Would it?

Comment: I wasn't able to inspect on codepen but that does seem to be the case, you are right. If it is a bit outside the container I would experiment with the margin on the right class. That should help you align it within the container.